# That and which in specific sentence

Tags: difference, relative-pronouns

Which sounds more natural in this sentence:

> Names have power which you can summon.

or

> Names have power that you can summon.

Or maybe there's a difference in meaning or usage context that I can't seem to understand, because I'm not native English speaker. Either way, I need help with this one.

Comment: In US English, the *which* version would be considered unidiomatic, if not actually ungrammatical. (Depending on how strictly somebody applied rules about only using *that* in such a phrase.) In UK English, *that* and *which* are used somewhat interchangeably in this construction.

Answer (score 0):

Both are possible, "which" might be preferred.

The second clause "which you can summon" is describing the power that names have. In this situation "which" is sometimes preferred.  The sentence could be rephrased with "and". This is an indication that "which" might be a better choice.

> Names have power, and you can summon this power.

However, this is strictly a matter of style. And "that" would also be correct and idiomatic in this context.